# Confluent schema-registry how to http post json-schema

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

Confluent 5.5.0 understands not just Avro schemas, but also json-schema and protobuf. I have a valid json-schema that I'm trying to curl to the schema registry server, but I keep getting the response

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
     --data @$tmpfile ${schemaregistry}/subjects/${topic}-value/versions?schemaType=JSONSCHEMA
{"error_code":42201,"message":"Either the input schema or one its references is invalid"}
```

[The manual](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#post--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions) is unclear about how to use the `schemaType` parameter. I've tried as a query parameter, as a field in the json, ...
The `$tmpfile` I'm posting is a json with one top-level field named `schema` that contains a quote-escaped json-schema. The same mechanism works perfectly for Avro schemas.

Looking in the logging from the schema registry, I see that it tries to parse the provided data as an Avro schema, so no wonder it fails.

Any help? And Confluent: please clarify *and fix* your documentation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah I got it. The documentation is unclear *and* wrong!

You have to add a field *inside the posted json*. The field name is `schemaType`, and its value must be `JSON`, and not `JSONSCHEMA` (what the documentation says).

For others here's an example that shows how to put local files with an avro and json schema into the schema-registry:

```
#!/bin/bash
schemaregistry="$1"
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

topic=avro-topic
export SCHEMA=$(cat schema.avsc)
echo '{"schema":""}' | jq --arg schema "$SCHEMA" '.schema = $schema' \
   > $tmpfile
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
    --data @$tmpfile ${schemaregistry}/subjects/${topic}-value/versions

topic=json-topic
export SCHEMA=$(cat schema.json)
echo '{"schema":"","schemaType":"JSON"}' | jq --arg schema "$SCHEMA" '.schema = $schema' \
   > $tmpfile
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
    --data @$tmpfile ${schemaregistry}/subjects/${topic}-value/versions
rm $tmpfile
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Confluent schema registry API documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#get--schemas-types-) one can check the supported schema types by calling

```
curl --silent -X GET http://localhost:8081/schemas/types
```

This should result in

```
["JSON","PROTOBUF","AVRO"]
```

for the current version (5.5) so the output might help to set a proper schemaType-attribute.

Nonetheless as @bart van deenen pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821404/5587258), the API doc is (still) wrong.